# using asp.net mvc “membership” for mysql database throws Keyword not supported. Parameter name: attachdbfilename

Tags: mysql, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, vb.net, asp.net-mvc-4

I am new to asp.net programming and I am lost. I hope this is an easy error for someone. In general I can't register/login in the default VS 2013 asp.net mvc internet site while using mysql db.

My web.config

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!--
  For more information on how to configure your ASP.NET application, please visit
  http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=301880
  -->
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <!-- For more information on Entity Framework configuration, visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=237468 -->
    <section name="entityFramework" type="System.Data.Entity.Internal.ConfigFile.EntityFrameworkSection, EntityFramework, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false" />
  </configSections>
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="DefaultConnection" connectionString="Data Source=(LocalDb)\v11.0;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\aspnet-fmERP-20140911115749.mdf;Initial Catalog=aspnet-fmERP-20140911115749;Integrated Security=True" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
    <add name="fmerpEntities" connectionString="metadata=res://*/Model1.csdl|res://*/Model1.ssdl|res://*/Model1.msl;provider=MySql.Data.MySqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;server=127.0.0.1;user id=root;password=zzr400;persistsecurityinfo=True;database=fmerp&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
    <remove name="LocalMySqlServer" />
    <add name="LocalMySqlServer" connectionString="server=127.0.0.1;Uid=root;database=fmerp;password=zzr400" providerName="MySql.Data.MySqlClient" />
  </connectionStrings>
  <appSettings>
    <add key="webpages:Version" value="3.0.0.0" />
    <add key="webpages:Enabled" value="false" />
    <add key="ClientValidationEnabled" value="true" />
    <add key="UnobtrusiveJavaScriptEnabled" value="true" />
  </appSettings>
  <system.web>
    <sessionState mode="Custom" cookieless="true" regenerateExpiredSessionId="true" customProvider="MySqlSessionStateProvider">
      <providers>
        <add name="MySqlSessionStateProvider" type="MySql.Web.SessionState.MySqlSessionStateStore, MySql.Web, Version=6.8.3.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=c5687fc88969c44d" applicationName="/" description="" connectionStringName="LocalMySqlServer" writeExceptionsToEventLog="False" autogenerateschema="False" enableExpireCallback="False" />
      </providers>
    </sessionState>
    <profile defaultProvider="MySQLProfileProvider">
      <providers>
        <remove name="MySQLProfileProvider" />
        <add name="MySQLProfileProvider" type="MySql.Web.Profile.MySQLProfileProvider, MySql.Web, Version=6.8.3.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=c5687fc88969c44d" applicationName="/" description="" connectionStringName="LocalMySqlServer" writeExceptionsToEventLog="False" autogenerateschema="True" enableExpireCallback="False" />
      </providers>
    </profile>
    <roleManager defaultProvider="MySQLRoleProvider">
      <providers>
        <remove name="MySQLRoleProvider" />
        <add name="MySQLRoleProvider" type="MySql.Web.Security.MySQLRoleProvider, MySql.Web, Version=6.8.3.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=c5687fc88969c44d" applicationName="/" description="" connectionStringName="LocalMySqlServer" writeExceptionsToEventLog="True" autogenerateschema="True" enableExpireCallback="False" />
      </providers>
    </roleManager>
    <membership defaultProvider="MySQLMembershipProvider">
      <providers>
        <remove name="MySQLMembershipProvider" />
        <add name="MySQLMembershipProvider" type="MySql.Web.Security.MySQLMembershipProvider, MySql.Web, Version=6.8.3.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=c5687fc88969c44d" applicationName="/" description="MySQL default application" connectionStringName="LocalMySqlServer" writeExceptionsToEventLog="True" autogenerateschema="True" enableExpireCallback="False" enablePasswordRetrieval="False" enablePasswordReset="True" requiresQuestionAndAnswer="True" requiresUniqueEmail="False" passwordFormat="Clear" maxInvalidPasswordAttempts="5" minRequiredPasswordLength="7" minRequiredNonalphanumericCharacters="1" passwordAttemptWindow="10" passwordStrengthRegularExpression="" />
      </providers>
    </membership>
    <authentication mode="None" />
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5" />
    <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5" />
  </system.web>
  <system.webServer>
    <modules>
      <remove name="FormsAuthentication" />
    </modules>
  </system.webServer>
  <runtime>
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Newtonsoft.Json" culture="neutral" publicKeyToken="30ad4fe6b2a6aeed" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-6.0.0.0" newVersion="6.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Optimization" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-1.1.0.0" newVersion="1.1.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="WebGrease" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-1.6.5135.21930" newVersion="1.6.5135.21930" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Antlr3.Runtime" publicKeyToken="eb42632606e9261f" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-3.5.0.2" newVersion="3.5.0.2" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Helpers" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-3.0.0.0" newVersion="3.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.WebPages" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-3.0.0.0" newVersion="3.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Mvc" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-5.2.2.0" newVersion="5.2.2.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.Owin" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-3.0.0.0" newVersion="3.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.Owin.Security" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-3.0.0.0" newVersion="3.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.Owin.Security.Cookies" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-3.0.0.0" newVersion="3.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.Owin.Security.OAuth" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-3.0.0.0" newVersion="3.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
    </assemblyBinding>
  </runtime>
  <entityFramework codeConfigurationType="MySql.Data.Entity.MySqlEFConfiguration, MySql.Data.Entity.EF6">
    <defaultConnectionFactory type="System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.SqlConnectionFactory, EntityFramework" />
    <providers>
      <provider invariantName="MySql.Data.MySqlClient" type="MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlProviderServices, MySql.Data.Entity.EF6" />
    </providers>
  </entityFramework>
</configuration>
```

I get the folloing error:

```
   Source Error:


Line 59:         ' This doesn't count login failures towards account lockout
Line 60:         ' To enable password failures to trigger account lockout, change to shouldLockout := True
Line 61:         Dim result = Await SignInManager.PasswordSignInAsync(model.Email, model.Password, model.RememberMe, shouldLockout := False)
Line 62:         Select Case result
Line 63:             Case SignInStatus.Success


Source File: c:\users\cstamoultas.npas\documents\visual studio 2013\Projects\fmERP\fmERP\Controllers\AccountController.vb    Line: 61

Stack Trace:


[ArgumentException: Keyword not supported.
Parameter name: attachdbfilename]
   MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlConnectionStringBuilder.GetOption(String key) +138
   MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlConnectionStringBuilder.set_Item(String keyword, Object value) +50
   System.Data.Common.DbConnectionStringBuilder.set_ConnectionString(String value) +181
   MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlConnectionStringBuilder..ctor(String connStr) +139
   MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlConnection.set_ConnectionString(String value) +359
   System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.Interception.DbConnectionDispatcher.<SetConnectionString>b__18(DbConnection t, DbConnectionPropertyInterceptionContext`1 c) +66
   System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.Interception.InternalDispatcher`1.Dispatch(TTarget target, Action`2 operation, TInterceptionContext interceptionContext, Action`3 executing, Action`3 executed) +138
   System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.Interception.DbConnectionDispatcher.SetConnectionString(DbConnection connection, DbConnectionPropertyInterceptionContext`1 interceptionContext) +478
   System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyInternalConnection.InitializeFromConnectionStringSetting(ConnectionStringSettings appConfigConnection) +316
   System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyInternalConnection.TryInitializeFromAppConfig(String name, AppConfig config) +79
   System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyInternalConnection.Initialize() +253
   System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyInternalConnection.get_ProviderName() +36
   ....
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Why would you use a Microsoft SQL Server connection string with Oracle MySQL?

Comment: I have both strings mssql & mssql. I found the problem and it is in identity function that calls the wrong string. Thank you for your post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change IdentityModels.vb

```
  Public Sub New()
    MyBase.New("DefaultConnection", throwIfV1Schema:=False)
End Sub
```

to

```
  Public Sub New()
    MyBase.New("LocalMySqlServer", throwIfV1Schema:=False)
End Sub
```

Comment: In my case I was actually using `DefaultConnection`, but I had to change my `connectionString` and `providerName`.